# How to run Azure WebJob from vNext Build?

Tags: azure, web-applications, asp.net-core, webjob

Is there any way to run an Azure WebJob from a vNext Build and deployment?
I have created a WebJob for my Azure Web App that gets triggered manually. It's currently working, and when it runs, it reads a dbscript.sql file and executes it against the Web App's database; this effectively updates my database. Now, I'd like to run this WebJob whenever my Web App is newly built and deployed, but not sure how to accomplish this in a vNext build definition.

Thanks,
Russ

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a way to call something on deploy. I'm not sure how you are deploying now, but let's assume you are using git. On the back end, Azure uses Kudu for the git deployments. You should be able to customize the Kudu scripts to call a powershell cmdlet to add an item to the queue, which then triggers the webjob. Look for the post-deployment hooks [Deploying ASP.NET 5 application to Azure Web App using Git or Mercurial](http://blog.dudak.me/2015/deploying-asp-net-5-application-to-azure-web-app-using-git-or-mercurial/)
and [post deployment hooks for Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks)

One thing to try that may even be simpler is simply call your code on Kudu's post-deployment hook (rather than trying to use a webjob) since the docs say

```
To add a post deployment action hook you simply need 
to place a script file (.bat or .cmd) under
 site\deployments\tools\PostDeploymentActions.
```

If you are doing the deployment locally, after deployment use azure-cli to trigger off webjob using the following command (you'll need to fill in the details for the job and site)
from  [azure-cli cheat sheet](http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/)

```
azure site job start
```

Back to the webjob - since you can't trigger off a WebJob via a restful method, you'll need to have your webjob triggered by a new queue message (if you choose to go that route). You can do this by powershell.
Check out How to insert a message into a queue in the following
[Using Azure PowerShell with Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-powershell-guide-full/) which will then in turn trigger your webjob.

Lastly you could have a webjob running that is an ASP.NET 5 app and trigger that off as needed to perform your own actions. By that measure you could easily do the same with web api - but may be best in this case to just trigger the webjob via a queue message or use azure-cli, the config is relatively easy.